# Matlab (stem function) circles

Tags: matlab, geometry

I have this function

```
Y=fft(y); %fourier transformation
n=size(y,2)/2;
AS=abs(Y)/n;  %absolute value
set(figure, 'Position', [0 0 500 300]) %left,bottom,width,height
freq=(0:79)/(2*n*dt);
stem(freq,AS(1:80));
```

I don't want circles around abscissa axis. I want them only on top of graph.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. The circles are located at (freq(i),AS(i)) and not around the abscissa axis. Unless AS == 0, in which case that is where they should be.

Comment: How to create conditions that portrayed a value greater than 0 in AS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can skip plotting points where `AS` would be equal to 0.  Simply set these values to `NaN`, then plot your graph:

```
Y=fft(y); %fourier transformation
n=size(y,2)/2;
AS=abs(Y)/n;  %absolute value
set(figure, 'Position', [0 0 500 300]) %left,bottom,width,height
freq=(0:79)/(2*n*dt);

%// NEW
ASval = AS(1:80);
ASval(ASval == 0) = NaN;
stem(freq,ASval);
```

What will happen is that any points that are exactly 0 will not be plotted due to the insertion of `NaN`.  Any values that are non-zero will be plotted by `stem` normally.

---

In general, due to floating point precision, looking for elements that are exactly 0 may not bode well.  As such, it is good to check to see if values are within a specified threshold, and if they are, set these values to `NaN`.  Because your data is strictly positive, there isn't a need to check for values that are approaching from the negative side of the horizontal axis. As noted in your comments, you used `0.15`.  Therefore, you would simply do this instead of what I had above:

```
%// NEW
ASval = AS(1:80);
ASval(ASval < 0.15) = NaN;
stem(freq,ASval);
```

Comment: Thank you very much it works but i need to change ASval(ASval == 0) = NaN; to ASval(ASval < 0.15) = NaN;

Comment: @KarolVojtek - No problem!  I didn't know what exactly the threshold was, so I made it 0.  You can obviously make the threshold according to whatever is good for your data.  Good luck!